# Preloading custom objects from JSON files

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

I have a custom prototype function in javascript (Vector). Instances of these are stored as attributes in objects (tiles) held in a large array (allTiles) which has approx 1 million objects.

I have a lengthy and complex process which creates and populates this - it takes about 20 minutes to run. The results are static however and I'd like to pre-load them from a static JSON file to bypass the generation process.

I've been able to do this in the past using JSON.stringify and store the results in a separate js file. This however works better with native data types than with custom functions. When I do that in this instance I get a the localVector being represented as an object with the correct values - but not as an instance of Vector (with all its available methods etc).

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to construct a static JSON file where I could get to the same result as I would from this type of code (assume the vector function and prototype will of course be loaded prior to executing the code in this file).

Note - I have a hacky-workaround that I do not like where I create from JSON then iterate over the list and manually transform the objects into Vectors - this is much faster than generation from scratch but is still slow and I assume/hope there's a more correct approach.

Starting position from generation code:

```
//simple version of complex generation process
let allTiles = [];
let tile1 = {ID:abc, localVector : new Vector(x, y)};
allTiles.push(tile1);
//....repeat a million times 
//from this position code like this works fine: 
allTiles[0].localVector.add(anotherVector)
```

Vector prototype.

```
function Vector(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
}

Vector.prototype = {
    set: function (x, y) {
        this.x = x || 0;
        this.y = y || 0;
        return this;
    },

    add: function (v) {
        this.x += v.x;
        this.y += v.y;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: The major issue here is the fact that you cannot stringify functions. There is no valid JSON that can represent a function. I could only suggest looking at writing another JS file, however it would have to be done server-side.

Comment: As Dane said, JSON doesn't support any custom types. Anyways, you could use a custom reviver to convert these objects into an instance of your class. See [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter)